# Create array from string containing parent and child separators

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to convert this string to an array, while also not repeating "parent" keys. The parent seperater is `|` while child seperator is `>`.

Example string: `Progressivism and World War 1>Gender and Equality|Progressivism and World War 1>Social Change and Reform|The Great Depression and the New Deal`

In the above example "Progressivism and World War 1" has two children, namely: "Gender and Equality" and "Social Change and Reform".

End result should be:

```
[0] => [
  'name'   => 'Progressivism and World War 1'
  'parent' => false
],
[1] => [
  'name' => 'Gender and Equality'
  'parent' => 'Progressivism and World War 1'
],
[2] => [
  'name' => 'Social Change and Reform'
  'parent' => 'Progressivism and World War 1'
],
[3] => [
  'name' => 'The Great Depression and the New Deal'
  'parent' => false
],
```

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? While we're glad to help when you're stuck, you're still expected to make an effort of your own. If you have tried something, please share your attempt and explain where and how it fails to do what it needs.

Comment: @El_Vanja, apologies, I should of provided what I tried. My head was in another space. I approached it from a viewpoint that I had already tried everything on my end. I don't ever ask on stackoverflow unless I have tried everything. But I understand your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to split your string into multiple parts to get the different parts you need to build the array. You can do this in PHP with `explode(string delemiter, string input)`.

Then, loop through them and do the same again. Before adding to the array, check if there is a parent, if not set parent to false.

That's the solution i came up with:

```
<?php

$input = "Progressivism and World War 1>Gender and Equality|Progressivism and World War 1>Social Change and Reform|The Great Depression and the New Deal";
$result = [];

$parents = explode('|', $input);

foreach($parents as $parent) {
    $childs = explode(">", $parent);
    if(count($childs) === 1) {
        $result [] = [
            'name' => $childs[0],
            'parent' => false
        ];
    } else {
        $result [] = [
            'name' => $childs[1],
            'parent' => $childs[0]
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ein when you answer "requirements dumps" (questions that show absolutely no effort), you perpetuate the cycle of abuse on volunteers here.  Volunteers must not be treated as free code writters.  We are here to help, not here to do other people's work for free.  Please require more from askers before posting an answer.

Comment: Oh okay, so in the future I'll ask for more information instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not break the lines up based on the parent separator and build an associative array with the children nested inside?

Example string: Progressivism and World War 1>Gender and Equality|Progressivism and World War 1>Social Change and Reform|The Great Depression and the New Deal

Would become

```
['Progressivism and World War 1'] => ['Gender Equality', 'Social Change and Reform']
['The Great Depression and the New Deal'] => [...]
```

The parents are the outer keys and the children are associated to the parents automatically.  Should make looping and referencing the data easier.